# R; For each level in column A, replace values in column B, following condition in column C

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a list of species observations in N sites. Observations are presence, absence or unknown (1, 0, 'na'). What I need to do is, for each species, satisfy the condition:

*for each SITE, if no 1 %in% SITE, replace all 0 with 'na'*

I've managed a workaround using a nested loop and lists, but that seems horribly inefficient. Some questions pertaining matching values in column provided more elegant solutions, but I couldn't apply them in a more complex setting.

Here's some dummy data:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
site <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1)
sp1 <- factor(c(1,1,'na','na',0,0,'na','na','na',0))
sp2 <- factor(c(0,0,1,1,'na','na',0,1,'na','na'))
table <- cbind.data.frame(x,site,sp1,sp2)
```

And what I did:

```
for (j in c(3:4)){
  site.present <- unique(table$site[which(table[,j]==1)])
  for (i in (1:length(table[,j]))) {
    ifelse(!(table[i,2]%in%site.present), 
           ifelse(table[i,j]==0,table[i,j]<-'na',T),T)
  }
}
```

In this example [5,3] and [6,3] should become 'na' instead of 0 (because for sp1 there is no presence in site 2). The code above works, but it seems silly for processing millions of entries...

Much appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear: for each `site != 1` you would need to replace all `0`s with `"na"` in column `sp1`, right?

Comment: BTW Don't call your data `table` - that's the name of a function.

Comment: @markus In column `sp1` in this example, yes, but many more in the actual thing. And thanks for the naming suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *dplyr* and `base::replace`. We can replace any zero with NA where is no species equal to 1 in that site.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- table

df %>% mutate_all(~as.numeric(as.character(.))) %>% 
       group_by(site) %>% 
       #mutate(sp1_mod=replace(sp1,all(sp1!=1, na.rm = TRUE) & sp1==0,NA)) #for one column
       mutate_at(vars('sp1','sp2'), list(~replace(.,all(.!=1, na.rm = TRUE) & .==0,NA)))
```

Also, instead of naming variables inside `vars` one by one we can use one of the *Select helpers* see `?dplyr::select`, e.g. we can use `matches` to match any column names start with *sp* and with a digit or more

```
mutate_at(vars(matches('sp\\d+')), list(~replace(.,any(.==1, na.rm = TRUE) & .==0,NA)))
```

Comment: So much faster! Similar to @Paweł Chabros , but mutate_at makes this answer more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)

table %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(sp1 = if_else(
    !any(sp1 == 1) & sp1 == 0,
    "na",
    as.character(sp1)
  ))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Clean and fast, but I marked @A. Suliman 's answer (also dplyr) as accepted since there's a solution for multiple columns at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want a compact and fast solution that can be applied at once to an entire range from 1 to *n* species.

I would first **`reshape`** the data to a long format, and then set `NA` using `by` `sp*` if it is an element of `c(0, NA)` for each `site`. Thirdly, we could optionally `reshape` back to the original large format.

```
tmp <- reshape(dat, varying=list(3:ncol(dat)), v.names="sp", idvar=1:2, direction="long")
tmp <- do.call(rbind, by(tmp, tmp[c("site", "time")], function(x)
  if (all(x$sp %in% c(0, NA))) cbind(x[-4], sp=NA) else x))
dat <- reshape(tmp, timevar="time", idvar=c("x", "site"), direction="wide", sep="")
dat
#         x site  sp1  sp2
# 1.1.1   1    1    1    0
# 2.1.1   2    1    1    0
# 3.1.1   3    1 <NA>    1
# 10.1.1 10    1    0 <NA>
# 4.2.1   4    2 <NA>    1
# 5.2.1   5    2 <NA> <NA>
# 6.2.1   6    2 <NA> <NA>
# 7.3.1   7    3 <NA>    0
# 8.3.1   8    3 <NA>    1
# 9.3.1   9    3 <NA> <NA>
```

If we want more speed we could use `melt` and `dcast` for the reshape process from the **`data.table`** package which almost doubles the speed. The code changes slightly:

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- melt(dat, id.vars=c("x", "site"), variable.name="time", value.name="sp")
tmp <- do.call(rbind, by(tmp, tmp[c("site", "time")], function(x)
  if (all(x$sp %in% c(0, NA))) cbind(x[-4], sp=NA) else x))
dcast(tmp, x + site ~ time, value.var="sp")
```

To test if both works, expand the dataset to the number of Zoraptera species, which is 28, and run the code again:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 28 - 2
add <- setNames(as.data.frame(
  replicate(n, factor(sample(c(1, 0, NA), nrow(dat), replace=TRUE)))), 
  paste0("sp", 3:(n + 2)))
dat <- cbind(dat, add)
```

***Data***

```
# I'd rather use a neutral name for the data, since `table` is a function name, see `?table`
dat <- structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), site = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1), sp1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "na"), class = "factor"), 
    sp2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1", "na"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

# first thing to do is make proper NAs!
levels(dat$sp1) <- levels(dat$sp2) <- c(0, 1, NA)
```

Comment: Definitely the cleanest answer, but it gave me more trouble to go through many species. Also, thanks for the proper NA suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @jay.sf . For some reason I can't get the sapply to work (it just stays the same). But anyway, I was sloppy checking your code before, so my previous comment was actually misleading, sorry for that.
This is replacing all 0 for NA in all sites that are not site_1. But the idea is to do it just at the sites for which there is no presence of a given species.
In biology terms, a species may not occur (0) in site/region X because it can't (e.g. soil type), or because it never got there (e.g. island). To know if it's soil or not, only the first case matters.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, I think now I heard the bell ringing from what you want. See my edited answer and tell me what you think.